# eclipse auto formate : How to stop new line after dot of method call?

Tags: eclipse, preferences

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

This line:

**A**

```
winterwell.jtwitter.Status status = twitter.updateStatus(statuses[0]);
```

Is formatted like this

**B**

```
winterwell.jtwitter.Status status = twitter  
     .updateStatus(statuses[0]);
```

I want to keep it like in **A**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is occurring because of your `Maximum line width` setting.  You might want to increase yours, or look at the other options available for wrapping.

Go to Window > Preferences... Java > Code Style > Formatter > Edit...
[image]

Maximum line width
[image]

Answer (score -1):

In my case helped Eclipse restart after I realised setting Maximum line width to 500 didn't help :-D

.. probably some kind of bug of:

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600